# Bokeh Div text alignment with variables in header

Tags: html, css, bokeh, figure

I have a question based on this answer: [Bokeh Div Text Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183352/bokeh-div-text-alignment)

```
text = """
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: center;}
div {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>This is a div.</div>
</body>
</html>
"""
show(Div(text=text))
```

Now I have a variable:
Names = ["filename1", "filename2", "filename3"]

and the `show(Div(text=text))` code is inside a for-loop iterating over "Names" which generates a bokeh figure for each file. I tried the following:

```
<h1>Names[i]</h1>
```

but now the text in the figure with div is literally "Names[i]" instead of its content "filename1". How can i change the html code in order for it to use the "filename1" text stored inside Names[i] in the header ????

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.